# PayPal doesn't redirect to my return URL after purchase ends

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-sandbox

In `My Account` > `Selling online` > `Website preferences` > `Auto Return` is set to **On**.

Existing, live (non-localhost) `Return URL` is provided as well.

`PayPal Account Optional` is set to `Off`, as adviced.

Despite that, after finalizing transaction no redirect happens.

My payment button:

```
 <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="[seller's email]">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Lorem ipsum">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="PLN">
  <input type="hidden" name="email" value="[buyer's email]">
  <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
  src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/pl_PL/PL/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif"
  alt="PayPal">
</form>
```

Comment: Did you set a return URL in your Sandbox account? A sandbox button will not return to the URL you set in your live account.

Comment: I see now that using sandbox requires using sandbox accounts as well, but I [had](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32093027/in-sandbox-preferences-auto-return-url-keeps-switching-itself-from-on-to-off) problem with saving preferences in sandbox. In the end I've figured it out by pasting return URL into hidden input value instead.